# Instagram Permission Request without Login Process in Screencast

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I'm struggeling with the Instagram Permssion Request. We need to use the API to scan for new uploads to Instagram with a specific hashtag, to trigger a machine.

For this, i tried to request the permission for "basic" and "public content". The request was declined for several times, primarily because the screencast does not contain any Instagram login process in our app. Since there is no need to login for our purpose, i dont know how to realize this. We also dont want to use any 3rd party tool, but just the Instragram API. Do you have any advice for this?

Answer (score 0):

Instagram does not approve one-off projects for yourself, they only give permission if you are creating an app or platform for many to use.

https://www.instagram.com/developer/authorization/

> One-off Projects. If you are an agency building websites or other
>   integrations, note that we don't grant permissions to clients created
>   for one-off projects. If you are interested in building a product,
>   platform, or widget that will be used as a service across multiple
>   projects, then you may submit a single client_id that you can use
>   across multiple projects.

If you are creating an app/platform you have to have a login flow for each customer to login and use, so you have show login flow in video screencast.

If you are not building an app/platform for wide audience, you probably will not get permission and are expected to use other apps out there that do what you want to do.

Also checkout the Instagram Graph API, this is API for business accounts to create one-off projects to moderate your accounts, but you will not have access to public hashtag posts, you will have access to all content for your account: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/v2.10

Comment: This is not a one-off project, but furthermore for a fix installed machine in a mall, which shall trigger a printer, whenever someone uploads a picture to instagram with a certain hashtag. there have to be a way to realize this. i don't really get, why instagam is not interested in sharing pictures :/

Comment: you cannot let anyone print anyone's hashtag photo, unless you have permission to use their media, if you let users login and show that user's photos to print, then you have a chance to get approved i think. You have to show clearly in your screencast, login process, loading of images, and printing, and show marketing documentation/website explaining the mall kiosk concept.

Comment: no, its not about printing a picture! its about getting informed, whenever someone is posting something with a certain hashtag. the printer prints out a voucher, not the picture !

Comment: so then you dont need `public_content`, you just need `basic`, ask user to login and you can get their photos and hashtags and print what u want, u will easily get permission for basic, public_content is difficult

Comment: you mean i can query the api for a certain hashtag with the **basic** permission? but i still dont have a login process to demonstrate. 
still, we just want to query the api frequently to be informed about new posts with a specfic hashtag

Comment: with basic u can query hashtag for only your photos, only your photos which have the hashtag, u still have to login

Comment: ..which does not help for our usecase :/ it seems, instagram does not accept any other permissions anymore?

Comment: that is correct, u can only get basic permission now